# Total number of subview in a view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to count total no of subview in a view and also release that subviews in my iphone application how i can do it? provide me suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//count subviews
NSUInteger count = [[view subViews] count];

for (UIView *v in [view subViews])
{
  [v removeFromSuperView];

  //if 'v' was not autoreleased add next line as well
  [v release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * subviews = [view subviews];
int count = [subviews count];
for(UIView * v in subviews)
{
  [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count total no of subview in a view

```
NSUInteger count = view.subviews.count;
```

> and also release that subviews in my iphone application

**Don't**. The view retains its subviews for you. Just add and remove views as needed, and let the view system handle reference counting correctly. If you need to retain a reference, hold that reference elsewhere (in your own variables).